# File type validation in strapi v4

Tags: node.js, file-upload, strapi

I am using strapi as my backend. I have some fields in collection from which some should accept only zip file while some should accept only images etc.

I selected file type from datatypes available in strapi.
[image]

Though I have not selected images as data type but when I hit the endpoint with postman passing an image in the field then it accepts the image which I believe that obvious behavior as image is also one type of file.

My question is that is there any validation I can put such that these fields should allow only zip or whatever type of file I want to upload?

Answer (score 1):

there is no known build in solution for validating fields, however there is few options that executing before entity creation process started:

1. model lifecycle, `beforeCreate` event
2. policy
3. middleware

So google suggests `beforeCreate` should prevent entity creation if you throw an error:

###### First, let's create an content-type that has `media` field that accepts `single` media file.

let's create lifecycles file for this content type:
`src/api/contentType/content-types/contentType/lifecycles.js`

```js
const { ForbiddenError } = require("@strapi/utils").errors;
module.exports = {
  beforeCreate(event) {
    const { data, where, select, populate } = event.params;
    // PLS NOTE THAT LINE MAYBE DIFFERENT IF YOU CREATE FROM ADMIN VS REST
    const media = await strapi.db
      .query("plugin::upload.file")
      .findOne({ where: { id: data.media } });

    if (media.mime !== "application/x-zip-compressed")
      throw new ForbiddenError("File is not ZIP");
}
```

[image]

P.S. Tested with `create` from `admin ui` if you create via `rest api` the part with `media` maybe different

Comment: its not working anymore

Comment: Yes current version gonna need to use setTimeout(), and afterCreate, since relations aren’t populated by default anymore

Comment: The file usually created and available for allocation after afterCreate is fired…

Answer (score 1):

you could do this if you want to check file type

```
module.exports = {
  beforeCreate(event) {
    const ctx = strapi.requestContext.get();
    // for access to file you have to replace "file.attachment" with your own filed name
    const fileType = ctx.request.files["files.attachment"].type;
    if (fileType !== "YOUR_FILE_TYPE") {
       return ctx.badRequest("SEND ERROR MESSAGE TO FRONT"); 
     }
    // do other thing if your file accepted
}
```